dropdown usando cakephp y vue no se llena cuando cake esta en modo production
Estimados estoy trabajando con cakephp 4 y vue uso una variable de entorno de windows que es consumida por cake para setear el modo desarrollo o produccion, ademas, lleno un  dropdown desde una bd. Mi problema es que el mencionado dropdown en modo produccion no se llena, aun recuperando los datos correctamente, lo cual he verificado con un console.debug.
Alguien sabe en que puede estar influyendo el modo production ?

le estas pegando a otra db... como podriamos saber que pasa sin un escenario que nos diga algo???

Sin un [mcve], veo difícil que alguien pueda decir con exactitud qué está pasando. Sospecho que las posibilidades son muchas como para intentar escribir una respuesta a esto.
